# why should i transpose in neural network in matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I would like to ask a question about matlab transpose symbol. For example in this case:

```
input=input';
```

It makes transpose of input but i want to learn why we should use transpose via usin Artificial Neural Network in matlab?

Second Question is:

I am trying to create a classification using ANN in matlab. I showed results like that:

```
a=sim(neuralnetworkname,test)
```

test is represens my test data in Neural network.
and the results is like that:

a =

Columns 1 through 12

```
2.0374    3.9589    3.2162    2.0771    2.0931    3.9947    3.1718    3.9813    2.1528    3.9995    3.8968    3.9808
```

Columns 13 through 20

```
3.9996    3.7478    2.1088    3.9932    2.0966    2.0644    2.0377    2.0653
```

If the result of a is about 2, it would benign, if the result of a is about 4,it is malignant.
So, I want to calculate that :for example,there are  100 benign in 500 data.(100/500) How can i write screen this `100/500` 
I tried to be clear, but if i didn't clear enough, I can try to explain more.Thanks.

Comment: Could you please be more clear? The title does not correspond to an actual problem in the question. In general the nature of your problem remains unclear while you seem to present some unnecessary details.

Answer (score 0):

**First Question**

You don't need to transpose input values everytime. Matlab ***nntool*** normally gets input values column by column by default. So you have two choice: 1. Change dataset order 2. Transpose input

**Second Question**

Suppose you have matrix like this:

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0];
```

To count how many elements below 8, write this:

```
sum(a<8) %[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0]
```

Output will be:

```
10
```